# How to convert string data type to date type in databricks sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to convert string data type to date data type.

For Example string column that is dob is like 12151987 and I want to convert this column in date data type like
12-15-1987.

I tried to_date(dob,'dd-MM-yyyy') but it's giving null value.

Comment: which databricks are you using azure,aws or community?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the source format.
Try below one -

```
select to_date("12151987", "MMddyyyy") as dt
```

To get the format that you have mentioned, use below one -

```
select date_format(to_date("12151987", "MMddyyyy"), "MM-dd-yyyy") as dt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%sql 
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE('12151987', 'MMddyyyy'), 'MM-dd-yyyy') AS formatted_date;[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]